# Como carregar um dropdown com um valor selecionado

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho um método para realizar alteração em alguns dados. Dentre esses dados, tenho um *dropdownlist* que contém os períodos dos cursos. Quando eu seleciono para alterar, preciso que o *dropdown* venha com a opção marcada, conforme está no banco de dados.

Preciso que ele venha selecionado "Noite", conforme está no banco:

[image: Preciso que ele venha selecionado "Noite", conforme está no banco]

Aqui está o *select* do *dropdown*. O `@ViewBag.Periodos` eu passo através do método `Alterar` no *Controller*:

```
<select name="selPeriodo" class="form-control">
      @{
          foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Periodos)
          {
             <option value="@item.Id">@item.Nome</option>
          }
       }                
</select>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A forma mais sucinta de escrever isso é assim:

```
<select name="selPeriodo" class="form-control">
      @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Periodos)
      {
         <option value="@item.Id" @(Model.PeriodoId == item.Id ? "selected" : "")>@item.Nome</option>
      }
</select>
```

A forma recomendada é assim:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PeriodoId, ((IEnumerable<Periodo>)ViewBag.Periodos).Select(periodo => new SelectListItem {
    Text = periodo.Nome,
    Value = periodo.Id,
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.PeriodoId == periodo.Id)
}), "Escolha um Período", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Acredito que não tenha resposta melhor

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Ia comentar a sua, mas você excluiu :(

Comment: Tranquilo, sua resposta está mais completa então não tenho porque manter a minha.

Comment: Manda muito. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez pela resposta e aos demais também!

Comment: Sempre precisarei passar usando uma ViewBag ou teria outro jeito? Estou tentando implementar algo parecido só que usando uma ViewModel, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Você pode colocar os valores da DropDown dentro da ViewModel, embora isso dê um pouco mais de trabalho. Faça outra pergunta que te apresento a abordagem detalhada.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Fiz uma pergunta mais detalhada do meu problema. Segue o link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184758/pegar-um-item-selecionado-no-dropdownlistfor-usando-uma-viewmodel-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3):

Faz um `FOR` buscando a lista de períodos e faz um `SELECT` retornando os valores do curso fora do `FOR`.

Daí dentro do `FOR` você faz um `IF` verificando se o campo que está sendo listado é igual ao campo do curso. Se for, você determina o `SELECTED` no campo `OPTION`.

```
<select name="selPeriodo" class="form-control">
      @{
          foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Periodos)
          {
             if (@item.id == @periodo) // Campo do FOR = Campo Período do Curso
             {
                 <option value="@item.Id" selected>@item.Nome</option>
             }
             else
             {
                 <option value="@item.Id>@item.Nome</option>
             }
          }
       }                
</select>
```

Provavelmente meu código em C# está errado porquê eu não programo em C#, mas entendo a lógica da rotina.

Comment: Você foi mais rápido haha +1

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não sei como está no seu cxontroller, mas eu tentaria isso aqui no controller

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.PediodoId = new SelectList(db.Periodos, "Id", "Nome", curso.PeriodoId);
```

e isso aqui na **View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PeriodoId, "PeriodosId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("PeriodoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })


@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PeriodoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```