# Pegar um item selecionado no Dropdownlistfor usando uma ViewModel ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel, dropdownlist

Estou tentando cadastrar uma SubCategoria que precisa de uma Categoria. Tenho a SubCategoriaViewModel, onde criei os campos `public IEnumerable<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias { get; set; }` e `public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }`. Tbm tenho `public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }` pro EF.

**Minha dúvida é**: como eu implementaria para eu receber no meu *Controller* a Categoria selecionada na *View*?

Na minha *ViewModel* tenho isso:

```
public class SubCategoriaViewModel
    {
        public SubCategoriaViewModel()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid SubCategoriaId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Preencha o nome da SubCategoria."))]
        [MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = ("Máximo {0} caracteres."))]
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = ("Mínimo {0} caracteres."))]
        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        public string SubCategoriaNome { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias { get; set; }
        public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }

        //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        //public DomainValidation.Validation.ValidationResult ValidationResult { get; set; }

        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    }
```

Na minha *View* tenho isso:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @* Este aqui tá dando certo aparecer na tela, mas não imagino um implementação para pegar um item selecionado *@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
                 new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "CategoriaNome"), new { @class = "form-control" })

                @* Esse aqui é so pra teste *@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
                 new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "CategoriaNome"), ((IEnumerable < Categorias)), new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

No meu *Controller* da SubCategoria tenho isso:

```
 // GET: SubCategorias/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            subCategoriaViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
            return View(subCategoriaViewModel);
        }

        // POST: SubCategorias/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(
            SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel)
        {
            subCategoriaViewModel =
                _subCategoriaAppService
                .Adicionar(subCategoriaViewModel);


            return View(subCategoriaViewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Seu modelo não vem preenchido quando da o post ? Seu model.CategoriaId contém o valor escolhido no dropdown.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves Realmente vc tinha razão. Já estava com o que eu queria, mas tenho outro problema. Quando adiciono uma nova SubCategoria, o `Dropdwonlist` fica vazio. Para concertar isso, preciso sair desta tela e depois voltar pra ela.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves Como faço para o `Dorpdwonlist` ficar sempre populado?

Comment: desculpe a demora, você conseguiu ?

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves Sem problemas. Ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iago, acredito que só seja necessário você repopuplar as categorias no `post` novamente.

```
// POST: SubCategorias/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(SubCategoriaViewModel subCategoriaViewModel)
{
    subCategoriaViewModel =
                _subCategoriaAppService
                .Adicionar(subCategoriaViewModel);

    subCategoriaViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
    return View(subCategoriaViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela a sua solução!

Comment: Realmente era isso o que estava faltando.

Answer (score 1):

**Como receber a categoria selecionada no dropdown?**

Quando você utiliza:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId,
                new SelectList(Model.Categorias, "CategoriaId", "CategoriaNome"), 
                new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Será gerado:

```
<select id="CategoriaId" name="CategoriaId">
    <option value="1">Categoria 1</option>
    <option value="2">Categoria 2</option>
                   .
                   .
                   .
    <option value="N">Categoria N</option>
</select>
```

Isso quer dizer que quando for selecionado um item no dropdown, o campo `CategoriaId` receberá o `"value"` desse `select` gerado.

**Select retornando null:**

Quando é realizado o post, pelo seu código, você está enviando apenas o `CategoriaId`, mas não a lista, por isso não fica preenchido.

Para solucionar isso, basta no post, quando fizer o return view, setar novamente essas linhas(conforme mostrado na resposta do Pablo Vargas):

```
subCategoriaViewModel.Categorias = _categoriaAppService.ObterTodas();
return View(subCategoriaViewModel);
```

Uma alternativa seria executar esse get da lista diretamente no seu modelo(se isso não ferir a arquitetura da sua solução), atribui a lista uma vez e sempre que fizer o get dessa propriedade verifica se a lista esta setada, caso não, faça o get dela novamente.

Comment: Gostei da sua explicação da solução do Pablo Vargas!

Comment: Sua explicação me ajudou a entender outros conceitos

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar.